# R: Plot a time series with quantiles using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I need to plot a time series with ggplot2. For each point of the time series I also have some quantiles, say 0.05, 0.25, 0.75, 0.95, i.e. I have five data for each point. For example:

```
time           quantile=0.05  quantile=0.25 quantile=0.5  quantile=0.75   quantile=0.95
00:01          623.0725       630.4353      903.8870       959.1407       1327.721
00:02          623.0944       631.3707      911.9967      1337.4564       1518.539
00:03          623.0725       630.4353      903.8870      1170.8316       1431.893
00:04          623.0725       630.4353      903.8870      1336.3212       1431.893
00:05          623.0835       631.3557      905.4220      1079.6623       1452.260
00:06          623.0835       631.3557      905.4220      1079.6623       1452.260
00:07          623.0835       631.3557      905.4220      1079.6623       1452.260
00:08          623.0780       631.3483      905.3496      1056.3719       1375.610
00:09          623.0671       630.4275      903.8839      1170.8196       1356.963
00:10          623.0507       630.0261      741.8475      1006.1208       1462.271
```

Ideally, I would like to have the 0.5 quantile as a black line and the others as shaded color intervals surrounding the black line. What's the best way to do this? I've been looking around with no luck, I can't find examples of this, even less with ggplot2.

Any help would be appreciated.

Salud!

Comment: Give us some data to play with. Here are some guidelines on how to make a great reproducible example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Does this do what you want? The trick to `ggplot` is understanding that it expects data in long format. This often means that we have to transform the data before it is ready to plot, usually with `melt()`.

After reading your data in with `textConnection()` and creating an object named `dat`, here are the steps you'd take:

```
#Melt into long format 
dat.m <- melt(dat, id.vars = "time")

#Not necessary, but if you want different line types depending on quantile, here's how I'd do it
dat.m <- within(dat.m
  , lty <- ifelse(variable == "quantile.0.5", 1
    , ifelse(variable %in% c("quantile.0.25", "quantile.0.75"),2,3)
    )
)

#plot it
ggplot(dat.m, aes(time, value, group = variable, colour = variable, linetype = lty)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_colour_manual(name = "", values = c("red", "blue", "black", "blue", "red"))
```

Gives you:

[image]

After reading your question again, maybe you want shaded ribbons outside the median estimate instead of lines? If so, give this a whirl. The only real trick here is that we pass `group = 1` as an aesthetic so that `geom_line()` will behave properly with factor / character data. Previously, we grouped by the variable which served the same effect. Also note that we are no longer using the `melt`ed data.frame, as the wide data.frame will suit us just fine in this case.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = time, group = 1)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = quantile.0.05, ymax = quantile.0.95, fill = "05%-95%"), alpha = .25) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = quantile.0.25, ymax = quantile.0.75, fill = "25%-75%"), alpha = .25) +
  geom_line(aes(y = quantile.0.5)) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "", values = c("25%-75%" = "red", "05%-95%" = "blue"))
```

[image]

**Edit: To force a legend for the predicted value**

We can use the same approach we used for the `geom_ribbon()` layers. We'll add an aesthetic to `geom_line()` and then set the values of that aesthetic with `scale_colour_manual()`:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = time, group = 1)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = quantile.0.05, ymax = quantile.0.95, fill = "05%-95%"), alpha = .25) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = quantile.0.25, ymax = quantile.0.75, fill = "25%-75%"), alpha = .25) +
  geom_line(aes(y = quantile.0.5, colour = "Predicted")) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "", values = c("25%-75%" = "red", "05%-95%" = "blue")) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = "", values = c("Predicted" = "black"))
```

There may be more efficient ways to do that, but that's the way I've always used and have had pretty good success with it. YMMV.

Comment: ggplot answers are like London buses.  You can wait three hours with nothing in sight, and then suddenly you have two inside 6 minutes!  PS. +1

Comment: Sounds like buses in Ljubljana a few years ago. :)

Comment: Wow, this is just about perfect! Thank you very much! The only thing I would need to add is a legend for the line which reads "predicted values". How could I do that? Can I combine scale_fill_manual with other scale_manual? Thanks again!

Comment: I tried adding `scale_linetype_manual(name="", values=c("predicted" = 1))` to no avail...

Comment: @inwit - Will update my answer now with one option to do this

Comment: Wow, now my graph is just how I wanted it to be. I'd post it here if I could. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your dat.frame is called `df`:

The easiest `ggplot` solution is to use the boxplot geom.  This gives a black central line with filled boxes to the middle and upper positions.

Since you have pre-summarised your data, it is important to specify the `stat="identity"` parameter:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=time)) + 
    geom_boxplot(
        aes(
          lower=quantile.0.25, 
          upper=quantile.0.75,
          middle=quantile.0.5,
          ymin=quantile.0.05,
          ymax=quantile.0.95
        ), 
        stat="identity",
        fill = "cyan"
)
```

[image]

PS. I recreated your data as follows:

```
df <- "time           quantile=0.05  quantile=0.25 quantile=0.5  quantile=0.75   quantile=0.95
00:01          623.0725       630.4353      903.8870       959.1407       1327.721
00:02          623.0944       631.3707      911.9967      1337.4564       1518.539
00:03          623.0725       630.4353      903.8870      1170.8316       1431.893
00:04          623.0725       630.4353      903.8870      1336.3212       1431.893
00:05          623.0835       631.3557      905.4220      1079.6623       1452.260
00:06          623.0835       631.3557      905.4220      1079.6623       1452.260
00:07          623.0835       631.3557      905.4220      1079.6623       1452.260
00:08          623.0780       631.3483      905.3496      1056.3719       1375.610
00:09          623.0671       630.4275      903.8839      1170.8196       1356.963
00:10          623.0507       630.0261      741.8475      1006.1208       1462.271"

df <- read.table(textConnection(df), header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Hmmm - we've interpreted his question differently...after re-reading it, I'm not sure who's on the right path here! Regardless, nice work showing how to manually create the box plots. +1

Comment: Yeah, I was more interested in the line & ribbon style, as my series is long. But thanks anyway, I learned something more! :)